# Getting GEOErrorDomain -209

Tags: ios, mapkit

Sometimes the `MKMapview` stops receiving tiles,
`mapViewDidFailLoadingMap` receives the error `"GEOErrorDomain error -209"`.

After a while, it restarts working.

It appens both with development and production version.

I cannot find any solution in Google, no one talks about  `"GEOErrorDomain error -209"`, only about  `"GEOErrorDomain error -204"`.

Answer (score 1):

I've contacted Apple service

they answered me that it's a bug of the MapKit framework